# Python - is there a way to automate this? <code>itertools.product</code>

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
x = np.arange(-1, 2)
a = np.array([i for i in product(x,x,x,x)])
```

This is I also need `np.array([i for i in product(x,x)])` and `np.array([i for i in product(x,x,x)])`... So I would like to automate `product` such that I just have to give an argument for the number of repetitions...

I tried to give `product` a list and a tuple, that does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`product` takes an optional integer argument specifying how many times you want to repeat the iterable argument.

```
np.array(product(x, repeat=2))
np.array(product(x, repeat=3))
np.array(product(x, repeat=4))
# etc
```

Comment: Produces `array(<itertools.product object at 0x10f7df480>, dtype=object)`.

Comment: Ah, `array` needs a list and not an arbitrary iterable? `array(list(product(...)))`.

Answer (score 2):

Write your own `product` for numpy, with a argument `repeat`, that says, how often `x` has to be repeated:

```
def np_product(x, repeat):
    result = np.ndarray((len(x),)*repeat + (repeat,))
    for n in range(repeat):
        index = (None,) * n + (slice(None),) + (None,) * (repeat-n-1)
        result[..., n] = x[index]
    return result.reshape(-1, repeat)

a = np_product(x, repeat)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 4
lst = [x for _ in range(n)]
[i for i in product(*lst)]
```

you can you * followed by a list as *args

Comment: `product(x,x,x,x)` works fine; the OP is looking for a way to parameter the count.

Comment: please note the it is *[list] to convert a list as *args

Comment: I know what the syntax means; but it's not answering the question the OP is asking. (Unless you include how you build the list in the first place.)

Comment: The OP clearly said "I tried to give product a list and a tuple, that does not work." My answer showed how passing a list as *args show be done in python